# I want to find an xpath element and confirm it is correct by checking the elements before and after it

Tags: c#, vb.net, xpath

I am using xpaths to run automation developed in C# using VB. I am having trouble finding an element and then confirming the element is correct by checking the previous element and following element.

Example:
I want to select the second "date" and then confirm it is the right "date" by checking to see if the element before "test2" and the element after "time2" are the right elements. Does that clear things up?

Alternatively:
I have been using Firepath on firefox to find the element. The command I have been working with is //preceding::*[contains(text(),'time2')]//*[contains(text(),'date')]//following::*[contains(text(),'test2')]

I have also added my html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div> this is a test 
   <div> <h1> test1 </h1> </div>
   <div> <h1> date </h1> </div>
   <div> <h1> time1 </h1> </div>
   <div> <h1> test2 </h1> </div>
   <div> <h1> date </h1> </div>
   <div> <h1> time2 </h1> </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So something on the lines of this?

```
/html/body/div/div[h1/text()=' date ' and preceding-sibling::div/h1/text()=' test2 ' and following-sibling::div/h1/text()=' time2 ']
```

or starting root and checking all, as yours does:

```
//div/div[h1/text()=' date ' and preceding-sibling::div/h1/text()=' test2 ' and following-sibling::div/h1/text()=' time2 ']
```